# Spreadsheet : Issue in fetching current user email id

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I am using Session.getActiveUser().getUserLoginId() to fetch the current user's email id but other than creator of the spreadsheet it is returning empty string. I have also used getEffetiveUser() but no hopes.

I will be appreciate if i could get some suggestions on this.

Many Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Chetan

Answer (score 0):

Quote from the Google documentation:

> If security policies do not allow access to the user's identity, User.getEmail() returns a blank string

Note that `User` in the above code is a sort of "placeholder" for the "User" class, which the `Session.getActiveUser()` returns.

If your script is set to:

> web app deployed to "execute as me"

You can not get the user email.

So, the one thing I can tell you for sure, is that your code does not have permission to get the user info.  I can't tell you why, because I don't know the conditions and settings under which your code is running.

[Link to Google Documentation for getActiveUser method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getActiveUser())

Comment: Hi , Thanks for your response. 
 
I have deployed to "User accessing the web app" but still it's not working. I will be waiting for your reply. Many Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure what is causing the problem.  This isn't really a programming question, so it doesn't fit stackoverflow.  You might try searching web applications, or joining a Google group.  [http://webapps.stackexchange.com/](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/) or [Google Apps Script Group](https://plus.google.com/u/0/communities/102471985047225101769)